# Transfer Odata query to SQL statement java

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I've been reading through the Olingo v4 server tutorials and all I have seen is examples with hard coded data. Are there any examples of using the v4 code with some type of sql backend. From what I've read JPA is not an option yet in v4. Is the expectation to parse the query and convert it to a sql statement that I would execute within my implementation? Is there any automation behind this somehow?

Update: I have been looking at a newer library called [JINQ](http://www.jinq.org/docs/) This looks promising. Does anyone have an idea of how to plug something like this into Olingo v4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Olingo v2, there is a JPA processor included. For Olingo v4, the decision was made to separate the JPA processor from the main project, the JPA processor becoming more of a component of Olingo v4.

Recently a major contribution was made to Olingo v4 with a first working version of a JPA processor. This JPA processor is still not yet officially approved but they are planning to integrate it and make an alpha version for other people to contribute to. You can find that first working solution here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-1010